# Make ajax POST without requiring a response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

Is there a way to make an $.ajax POST request:

1. without requiring a response
2. so the server doesn't even try to return anything

Are there some HTTP headers to accomplish this?  The goal would be to track statistics with minimal server and client request processing.

Comment: You can make a AJAX request without sending any response and you dont need any success/failure handler to set in the request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server should return a HTTP/204 No Content response. That's as close as you can get.

Comment: I was getting a little more long winded on this but I think this would work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is no problem in terms of security, and the amount of data you send is at maximum 2K minus the length of your URL, use a GET request instead. A GET request sends only one TCP packet, instead of two packets as a POST request does (first the header, then the data).